# Getting error when entering the following: from IPython.display import Image

Tags: python

Getting error when entering the following:

```
from IPython.display import Image, HTML
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pymc # I know folks are switching to "as pm" but I'm just not there yet
```

Comment: error says i do not have seaborn

Comment: also get error about pymc import

Comment: Can you include the full error message you get?

Comment: If the error says you don't have seaborn or pymc installed, then why on Earth are you asking here? Just install them! It's not rocket science.

Answer (score 0):

You likely don't have either Seaborn or PyMC installed. Apparently it's available via pip.